# Import Gradle project error

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded the latest Android Studio (Mac), I got this error when I try to create a new project:

Failed to import Gradle project: could not fetch model of type IdeaProject using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'

Would anybody know how I can move past this problem?

[image: Gradle error]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing in the **build.gradle** file:

```
:MyApplication1 -> :MyApplication1Project:MyApplication1
```

for all references

Comment: Hi. Similarly to the above answer, isn't settings.gradle a project level file? How is changing any of the project files going to help me when I go to create a new project? Thanks

Comment: No, settings.gradle I believe is in the parent directory MyApplication1Project/ directory. That's where I found mine. I believe the settings.gradle file is something to do with the project dependencies.

Comment: My mistake, I've corrected the file in question to build.gradle. See how that fares.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure without seeing your build.gradle file, but at line 9, do you have the line:

```
apply plugin: 'AppPlugin'
```

If this is the case the problem is that you're attempting to build an android application but you're applying the wrong plugin. If this is an Application, it should be:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

And if it's a library project then it should be:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

Again though, I can't say for sure if this is the problem because I haven't seen your build.gradle file.

Comment: Hi. Where can this file be found? Isn't it a project level file? This is happening when I try and create a brand new project. For existing projects, the build.gradle file is empty. It looks like this "// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules." Thanks

Comment: @theqs1000
Your top level build file should have something like this:
`buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.3'
    }
}`

And then the individual build files for each module need to start with one of the lines I have in my answer above

Comment: Where is the top level build file located? A search for it only reveals a "build.gradle.ftl". Is that it? It's buried deep in a directory called plugins/CloudEndpoint/lib/sdktemplates/GcmActivity/root

Comment: No, there should be a file called build.gradle in the top directory of your application's project folder.